# Why my Sitecore Explorer does not have "Manage Package" menu

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I need help, currently i'm working on how to rollback a package installation (*I've made a terrible mistake regarding a Sitecore deployment package*), and found a bitter truth about it.

So i just left my hope, and move on into a future precautions act.. i want to analyze any package before i deploy it. I search around and found **"Sitecore Rocks Anti Package"** could be my *"X-Ray Detector"*.

I'm trying to follow steps on this site ["28 Days of Sitecore Rocks"](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/trevor_campbell/posts/28-days-of-sitecore-rocks-package-management-part-1) and already tripped at early steps. I found no **"Manage Package"** Menu on my **Sitecore Explorer**.
[image]

There should be "Manage Package" menu like in that site tutorial.
[image]

Please help, i can't proceed further to learn the subject.
Btw, im using Visual Studio 2015 and Sitecore Rocks v 2.0.39.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use some of the advanced functionality in Sitecore Rocks you need to ensure that the connection type used is the **Hard Rock Web Service** and not the *Good Old Web Service*.

Modify your connection and ensure you are using Hard Rock Web Service:

[image: Hard Rock Web Service]

You should now have the `Manage Packages` option available allowing you to create anti-packages:

[image: Manage Packages Option]

If you are using [Sitecore Powershell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) module then a script exists to [create an anti-package](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/toolbox.html), the benefit is that it can be created on any server and not just instances connected to your Visual Studio (i.e. Production instances).

Comment: Ahh, i see! it works now..  though when i click "Test" it throws me an alert of 500 Internal server error, but when i ignore it and click "OK" instead, is successfully connected to my instance. weird, but it works, thank you very much and the lead on Sitecore Powershell Extensions, will dig around it soon. :-)